# Python: If Formula Not Working on Dataframe | ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with different currencies.  
I'm creating an if formula to apply to a specific column and give me the results in another column:

Code:

```
def CurConv(x):
    if rst[rst["Currency"]=="Botswana Pula(P)"]:
           return x*0.094
    elif rst[rst["Currency"]=="Brazilian Real(R$)"]:
           return x*0.2
    elif rst[rst["Currency"]=="Dollar($)"]:
           return x
    elif rst[rst["Currency"]=="Emirati Diram(AED)"]:
           return x*0.27
    elif rst[rst["Currency"]=="Indian Rupees(Rs.)"]:
           return x*0.014
    elif rst[rst["Currency"]=="Indonesian Rupiah(IDR)"]:
           return x*0.000070
    elif rst[rst["Currency"]=="NewZealand($)"]:
           return x*0.71
    elif rst[rst["Currency"]=="Pounds(å£)"]:
           return x*1.41
    elif rst[rst["Currency"]=="Qatari Rial(QR)"]:
           return x*0.27
    elif rst[rst["Currency"]=="Rand(R)"]:
           return x*0.073
    elif rst[rst["Currency"]=="Sri Lankan Rupee(LKR)"]:
           return x*0.0051
    elif rst[rst["Currency"]=="Turkish Lira(TL)"]:
           return x*0.12
    else:
        return "NaN"
rst["USD"]=rst.AverageCostfortwo.apply(CurConv)
```

But I keep getting this error:"ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous"

Comment: The issue here is that `apply` is going to pass you complete rows, one at a time.  You are assuming you'll get the cost value as a parameter, and I don't know how you thought you would get the current for the current row.  You need to check `x["Currency"] `, and you need to get the money value from whatever column that 's in, like `x["Cost"]`.

Comment: If you are trying to apply a formula to each row, the `if` statements are probably not the right way to approach this. Please give us an idea of what value you want to change (or what column you plan to add) from your DataFrame.

Comment: I have different currencies and just want to create one column with exchange values for USD

Comment: I posted in my answer explanations on why you got the error. @BenY, thanks for the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are hoping to get `True` if the result is not empty, you might want to use:

```
 if not rst[rst["Currency"]=="Botswana Pula(P)"].empty:
```

---

However, the issue here was not the `if` statement, looks like (from the comments you added later to  your question) you are trying to adjust the currencies to make a USD column. Here's my crack at it.

You can also do calculations by row, if you use the `apply()` method on the dataframe itself rather than its series components.

```
def CurConv(curr):
    '''Taking a row, return a value for the conversion factor'''
    if curr == "Botswana Pula(P)":
        return 0.094
    elif curr == "Brazilian Real(R$)":
        return 0.2
    elif curr == "Dollar($)":
        return 1
    elif curr == "Emirati Diram(AED)":
        return 0.27
    elif curr == "Indian Rupees(Rs.)":
        return 0.014
    elif curr == "Indonesian Rupiah(IDR)":
        return 0.000070
    elif currency == "NewZealand($)":
        return 0.71
    elif curr == "Pounds(å£)":
        return 1.41
    elif curr == "Qatari Rial(QR)":
        return 0.27
    elif curr =="Rand(R)":
        return 0.073
    elif curr == "Sri Lankan Rupee(LKR)":
        return 0.0051
    elif curr == "Turkish Lira(TL)":
        return 0.12
    else:
        return float("nan")

rst["USD"] = rst['AverageCostfortwo'] * rst['currency'].apply(CurConv)
```

Comment: Sorry I got fixated on the `if` statement initially.

Comment: It's ok, I'm very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

[**IMPORTANT**: please also vote up Ben Y's https://stackoverflow.com/a/67994153/206413]

To elaborate on the error, let's focus in the first statement:

```
if rst[rst["Currency"]=="Botswana Pula(P)"]:
       return x*0.094
```

Here, `rst["Currency"]=="Botswana Pula(P)"` is a **mask**, returning a `Series` of `True` or `False` for every row if the given row has `Currency == "Botswana Pula(P)"`

```
a = rst["Currency"]=="Botswana Pula(P)"
print(a[0]) # may be True or False given rst[0].Currency
print(a[1]) # may be True or False given rst[1].Currency
...
```

Then, `rst[rst["Currency"]=="Botswana Pula(P)"]` returns another `DataSet` with just the rows that satisfies the mask. Say `rst` has three rows and just the first satisfies the condition:

```
a = rst[rst["Currency"]=="Botswana Pula(P)"]
print(a.shape) # yields (1, <whatever>)
print('Yes' if a else 'No') # yields The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous
```

Since you cannot determine the truthiness of a DataSet

That said, I humbly *borrow* the answer from @BenY, https://stackoverflow.com/a/67994153/206413:

```
def CurConv(curr):
    '''Taking a row, return a value for the conversion factor'''
    if curr == "Botswana Pula(P)":
        return 0.094
    elif curr == "Brazilian Real(R$)":
        return 0.2
    elif curr == "Dollar($)":
        return 1
    elif curr == "Emirati Diram(AED)":
        return 0.27
    elif curr == "Indian Rupees(Rs.)":
        return 0.014
    elif curr == "Indonesian Rupiah(IDR)":
        return 0.000070
    elif currency == "NewZealand($)":
        return 0.71
    elif curr == "Pounds(å£)":
        return 1.41
    elif curr == "Qatari Rial(QR)":
        return 0.27
    elif curr =="Rand(R)":
        return 0.073
    elif curr == "Sri Lankan Rupee(LKR)":
        return 0.0051
    elif curr == "Turkish Lira(TL)":
        return 0.12
    else:
        return float("nan")

rst["USD"] = rst['AverageCostfortwo'] * rst['currency'].apply(CurConv)
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this, makes sense now

Comment: Masks are very powerful! Have great and joyful times with Pandas! :-)